# Using sinf() without a header on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I've been reading a lot of old C lately, and one common idiom is simply forward-declaring standard libraries instead of including the header file.  I wanted to try it, so instead of `#include <math.h>` I just declared

```
float sinf(float);
```

at the top of the file.  To my surprise, I got a link error!  I even tried manually including the math library like so:

```
clang++ -lm test.c
```

But alas, this gives me a linker error as well.  What gives?

**EDIT**

I was not enclosing the forward declaration in `extern "C"`...

Comment: You should always use the system headers. They can use various techniques to "decorate" the symbol names of the functions, so what you link to is not just the apparent function name with an underscore prefix. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/releasenotes/Darwin/SymbolVariantsRelNotes/index.html).

Comment: That article is pretty interesting!  I did take a look at my math.h and it seems to be vanilla.

Comment: Ah, ok so your notes on decoration made me realize that I was not enclosing my forward declaration in `extern "C"`.  I wonder why clang used the un-decorated version of sin() when telling me the symbol wasn't found.

Answer (score 2):

`-lm` should be put to the last parameter of compilation command. Try

```
clang test.c -lm
```

Comment: Ah, so it does work with clang but it does not with clang++.  I wonder what is different about C++ when it comes to linking with the math library.

Comment: @racarate In C++ it's wrapped in `namespace std`.

Comment: Hmm, putting it in extern "C" made it work -- doesn't that mean there was no std:: namespace on it?